# finding lines that contain n occurences of a certain pattern

Tags: regex, grep

I have a file containing lines that look like

```
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
```

My goal is to find lines containing  n occurences of the pattern "$long".

Anyone knowing the grep regex for this match?

Comment: Is `$long` exactly this value or a variable meaning another thing?

Comment: @Krischu I am scratching my head and wondering what made you think this was a design pattern question?

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: How do you think I'm thinking of a "design" pattern? regex pattern matching was the question.

Comment: @fedorqui: $long here is the pattern I wanted to form the regex for. And it stands for itself and is just a pattern as is. no special meaning of substituted by anything.

Comment: @Krischu You tagged the question as a `design-patterns` question. Diptendu edited the question to remove the wrong usage of the tag. Please click on the *design-patterns* tag and read the descirption. In general, always read a tag-wiki when you use the tag for the first time.

Comment: I should have mentioned: that contain n and only n occurences of the pattern.

Comment: @Chetan Kinger: Oh, now I understand. Sorry for the wrong tagging. It slipped through to me and I wasn't aware at all.

Comment: @Krischu you better update with what you *really* want to do, because it still looks a bit unclear

Answer (score 4):

You don't need a regex for this. With `awk` you can use `$long` as field separator and check how many fields each line has:

```
awk -v count=3 'BEGIN {FS="\\$long"} NF==(count+1)' file
```

#### Test

```
$ awk -v count=3 'BEGIN {FS="\\$long"} NF==(count+1)' a
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,
$ awk -v count=4 'BEGIN {FS="\\$long"} NF==(count+1)' a
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
$ awk -v count=5 'BEGIN {FS="\\$long"} NF==(count+1)' a
$
```

Comment: Might be an idea. I had in mind something like `grep "\(.*\$long\){5}" file` roughly speaking. That is looking for 5 (n)  occurences of $long with some garbage, but that wouldn't get me ^$long (at the begin of a line). A comma after the $long is alsway there despite the last in line.

Comment: Well, I don't think it is necessary to use a regex for this with the current explanation. But since you are providing more information here, may be good to update your question showing it, to make it more clear.

Comment: BTW, gawk - I don't have awk available at the moment - says: `gawk: cmd. line:1: warning: escape seuence '\$' treated as plain '$' `

Comment: @Krischu note I am using two \\ --> {FS="\\$long"}

Comment: @Krischu also, to get rid of the possible `$long` in the beginning of the line, just say FS=",\\$long". That is, prepend a comma.

Comment: yes, I was aware and I cut/pasted the command into gawk and it gave that warning.

Comment: @Krischu: Try `awk -F '\\$long' 'NF==4' file` It should work with non-gnu awk also

Comment: There is nothing gawk-specific about the above. @Krischu you (or your editor) did something wrong when you cut/paste the script.

Answer (score 2):

[`awk` solution by Fedorqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31055408/548225) should work fine. You can also use `grep` for this:

```
grep -E '(.*\$long){4}' file
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. My question contained "grep" and "regex". Thanks for all the awk stuff, but I was aiming grep and pattern matching. The awk solutions did not work for me - too awkward :) Did not work in gawk.

Comment: And I like this solution in so far as it reminds me on using the -E switch in grep (!)

Comment: On the other hand: as much as I like this solution, it doesn't work with me here. Oh, sorry, forgot the backslash (or did you edit meantime)?

Comment: The solution deserves one augmentation: when the string contains 5 occurences of $long  the grep (searching for 4 occurences also matches the lines that contain 5 occurences.

Comment: This command finds minimum of occurrences of search string i.e. `$long` in a given line. So it makes sure there are min 4 occurrences of  `$long`.

Comment: If one the answer here worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of the chosen answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81608/discussion-between-krischu-and-anubhava).

Comment: Sorry missed your chat invite as I was away. Yes `{5,5}` will find lines of exact 5 occurrences of `$lang`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v n=3 'gsub(/\$long/,"&")==n' file
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,

$ awk -v n=4 'gsub(/\$long/,"&")==n' file
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
```

but if `$long` can occur in contexts other than as a field of it's own, e.g.:

```
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC$longDEF",,$long,,,,
```

and you only want to count it when it's in a field of it's own then you'll need something more like:

```
$ awk -F, -v n=3 '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="$long") c++} c==n' file
```

e.g.:

```
$ cat file
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC$longDEF",,$long,,,,
```

Wrong:

```
$ awk -v n=3 'gsub(/\$long/,"&")==n' file
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,

$ awk -v n=4 'gsub(/\$long/,"&")==n' file
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC$longDEF",,$long,,,,
```

Right:

```
$ awk -F, -v n=3 '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="$long") c++} c==n' file
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC",,$long,,,,
A,B,1,2,3,$long,6,"A","",$long,,,,"ABC$longDEF",,$long,,,,

$ awk -F, -v n=4 '{c=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="$long") c++} c==n' file
E,F,2,3,4,$long,$long,$long,$long,,,"A","STRING";123456,,,1,2
```